# confidence interval for a linear fit to two data points with uncertainties

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting

I have two points, with coordinates x_1,2 and y_1,2, respectively. y is a measured value, which has an uncertainty associated with it.
I can calculate a straight line fitting the two points easily.
I can also estimate the uncertainties associated with the slope and intercept.
I would like to calculate/draw a confidence band.
Normally I would do this by:

```
serr = np.sqrt(np.sum(residuals**2)/(n - 2))
t = stats.t.ppf(1-0.05/2, n - 2)
confint = t * serr * np.sqrt(1./n + (x - np.mean(x))**2/np.sum((x-np.mean(x))**2))
```

The standard way using the standard error and the Student's distribution is not possible as the number of degrees of freedom is 0, n=2.
Is there an alternative way to estimate (and display) the confidence interval using the uncertainties associated with the slope and intercept?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say this should be "simple" error propagation. You propagate the `y`-errors into slope and intercept, where you have to pay attention that those will be correlated. With the known errors and the correlation one calculates the errors of a `y` to a given `x`

I'd do it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

"""
y = a + b x
"""
xl = [ 1, 2 ] ### x1 , x2
yl = [ .6, 1.8 ] ### y1 , y2
yerr = [ .5, .3 ] ### s1, s2

b = ( yl[1] - yl[0] ) / ( xl[1] - xl[0] ) ###  deltaX / deltaY
a = yl[0] - b * xl[0] 

xnp = np.linspace( -.5, 3, 200 )
ynp = np.fromiter( ( a + b * x for x in xnp ), np.float)

"""
Joel Tellinghuisen
J. Phys. Chem. A 2001, 105, 3917-3921

transformation of errors provides
(a)     ( s1^2 ( 1 + x1 / delatX )^2 + s2^2 ( x1 / deltaX )^2       , -s1^2 ( 1 + x1 / deltaX ) / deltaX - s2^2 x1 / deltaX^2   )
( ) ->  (                                                                                                                       )
(b)     ( -s1^2 ( 1 + x1 / deltaX ) / deltaX - s2^2 x1 / deltaX^2   , ( s1^2 + s2^2 ) / deltaX^2                                )

from this we calculate  sy^2 = sa^2+ sb^2 x^2 + 2 sab^2 x:
"""

def sy( x ):
    s1, s2 = yerr
    x1, x2 = xl
    dx = x2 - x1
    out  = ( s1 * ( 1 + x1 / dx ) )**2
    out += ( s2 * x1 / dx  )**2
    out += ( s1**2 + s2**2 ) / dx**2 * x**2
    out -= 2 * ( s2**2 * x1 / dx**2 + s1**2 * (  1 + x1 / dx ) / dx ) * x
    return np.sqrt( out )

ynpbp = np.fromiter( ( a + b * x + sy(x) for x in xnp ), np.float)
ynpbm = np.fromiter( ( a + b * x - sy(x) for x in xnp ), np.float)
ye = np.fromiter( ( sy(x) for x in xnp ), np.float)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.errorbar( xl, yl, yerr=yerr, marker='s', ls='' )
ax.plot( xnp, ynp )
ax.plot( xnp, ynpbp )
ax.plot( xnp, ynpbm )
ax.plot( xnp, ye )
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

which gives me the following plot

[image: graph with confidence]